# setup own web server

Tags: web-server, ssl-certificate

I want to setup my own web server for one of my websites. the site will be in php. I got the server configuration. there will be a linux(red hat) server with apache and mysql installed.

I have some question in my mind -

- Do I need a real IP for this?
- I also want SSL for the site, is it possible in it?

Comment: Be careful with black market IP addresses. They may look real to you at first glance, but many of them happen to be fake. An easy distinction is that fake IP addresses have an extra octet at the end.  I had an Uncle once who attempted to use a Fake IP address and a week later, the Feds were banging on his door. Oh! Did you mean external IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you'll likely want a real IP if you're hosting a website.
2. Yes.